# Difference between Perfect and Present relative time reference with the past participle form

Tags: adjectives, participles

> 1.They **filmed** the thief. (past tense--finite)

> 2.They saw the thief **filmed** in the act. (past participle--non finite)

Does "filmed" in the second sentence have a past or a present meaning relative to the reference time of the main verb in the sentence, "saw"? Although "filmed" as a non-finite form is classified as being *past* or *perfect* as well as *passive*, I believe that here, it can also convey the meaning of the *present passive*.

In other words, I believe that the second sentence could be validly rewritten as **either**

> 2a. They saw the thief, he **having been filmed** in the act.

> 2b. They saw the thief **being filmed** in the act.

Normally, the present passive participle must be specified by adding the auxiliary verb "being" in front of the past participle. Why is it that it is possible to omit the word "being" in sentence 2. while still allowing for that same present interpretation?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I believe OP has asked a worthwhile question re. the *tense* of the non-finite form -- does "filmed" refer to an action occurring *at the same time as* or *before* that of the main verb *saw*?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: *They saw the thief being filmed in the act* is a *very* peculiar thing to say. Did they know the person doing the filming? Was the person with the camera aware that "they" were watching him (and/or the thief) while he filmed the thief? The interactions between the three parties involved in the example are just too weirdly distracting for me to consider the actual *syntax*.

Comment: The sentence (#2) cannot really be nailed down time-wise.  It depends on what they're looking at:  the thief stealing as cameras nearby film the theft, or the playback of the film. +1 to FumbleFingers for "three parties".

Comment: Have you all read the latest META about questions being closed too often??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let’s analyze both of these sentences.

> They filmed the thief.

This is a simple declarative sentence, with the usual word order: subject (They), main verb (filmed), and direct object (the thief).  You were right: the verb *filmed* is past and finite. (The act of filming began and finished in the past.)  Other terms you might have heard for this verb form are **past indicative** and **preterite**.

> They saw the thief filmed in the act.

This is a more complex sentence.  The subject still comes first (they), then the main verb (saw).  The direct object is now a subordinate clause (the thief filmed in the act).  Let’s take a closer look at that last part.

As you observed, *filmed* is not a verb here.  The clause actually uses what’s called **the zero copula.**  The verb is really a form of *be*, but we leave it unsaid.  This sentence is actually short for something like:

> They saw the thief [who was] filmed in the act.

or

> They saw the thief [being] filmed in the act.

You can normally tell the meaning from context.  For example:

> She saw the thief filmed in the act and called the police. She testified at the trial. (Past continuous: she called the police while the filming was in progress, and testified after the filming was over.)

> Three weeks later, he saw the thief filmed in the act, at the supermarket. They didn’t make eye contact. (What your text calls past finite: the filming had finished three weeks before he saw the thief.)

So, if *filmed* isn’t a verb here, what is it?  In “the thief [who was] filmed in the act,” *filmed* modifies the noun *thief*, so it functions as an adjective.  This adjective is then modified by the adverbial phrase, “in the act.”  We call this type of adjective, formed from a verb, a past participle.

I said there’s another way to read the sentence: “the thief [being] filmed.”  This is the **passive** voice; you can normally turn a sentence like “They filmed the thief” into “The thief was filmed [by them].”  You can do this with any past participle (unless there’s some weird exception I forgot).  Let’s simplify a bit and look at the sentence: “The thief **was being** filmed by them.”  This changes the **aspect** from past finite to **past continuous**/**past progressive**.  (Which can also be called non-finite.)  For example, “The thief **was being** filmed by them when the police arrived,” means they were *still continuing* to film the thief/the filming was then *in progress*.

So I think, when your text described *filmed* in the second sentence as “non-finite,” the author was reading it as “They saw the thief [being] filmed in the act.”  That’s a valid reading, but not the only possible thing it could mean.  *Filmed* is definitely a past participle here, not the verb in this clause.  The thief was not filming anything.  You can't tell from the structure of the sentence alone: you could say, “I saw [that] Peter Jackson filmed in New Zealand.” But, in this context, “*The thief films in the act,“ does not make sense, so you can rule that out.

Regular English verbs use the *-ed* suffix for both preterite and past participle, but there are some irregular ones that have different forms, such as *take*/*took*/*taken*.  There is a pattern to some of these that makes them easier to memorize: strong verbs change the vowel in the past tense and often have a past participle that ends in *-en*.

Most verbs have past participles.  (Some helper verbs don’t.)  A few English words were originally past participles of verbs that are no longer used.  *Disgruntled* is more-or-less just an ordinary adjective today, and you won’t find the verb it originally came from in most dictionaries.  *Numb* is a very interesting example: it came from a verb that disappeared from the language centuries ago, and later, we made a new verb from it that means something different.  So, *numb* started out as a past particple, became an ordinary adjective, then a verb as well, and now that verb has its own past participle, *numbed*.